# How to set a specific tab when opening a Sliding Tab Layout activity?

Tags: android, tabs, sliding

I tried this [tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) and it works great, but now I would like to know if it is possible, when opening the application, to go directly to a specific tab and not the first one (at left) by default ?

Ex : I would like the application to open directly on "events" tab :

[image]

I searched into the code, but didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks folks

**EDIT :**
Here is the way :
Just add `pager.setCurrentItem(1);` in your MainActivity (the tabs container).

Comment: mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i); 
You should write in onCreate() method your activity class. mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> ViewPager is most often used in conjunction with Fragment, which is a
>   convenient way to supply and manage the lifecycle of each page.

You can use `setCurrentItem` // Set the currently selected page.

> Set the currently selected page. If the ViewPager has already been
>   through its first layout with its current adapter there will be a
>   smooth animated transition between the current item and the specified
>   item.

Finally,

```
Your_View_Pager_Obj.setCurrentItem(1); // call into onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code along with the viewPager and tablayout

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setCurrentTab(index)` in `onResume()` of MainActivity where `index` is the index of tab you want to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the MainActivity.java

```
private static final int EVENTS = 1;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(EVENTS);

    }
```